# Get days, weeks, months from a number of days in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, monthcalendar

Let's say I have 54 days, how can I calculate the number of months (assume 30 days per month), number of weeks and days for it javascript ?

For 54 days it should give : 1 month, 3 weeks, 3 days.
For 7 days it should give : 0 month, 1 week, 0 days.
For 13 days it should give : 0 month, 1 week, 6 days.
etc ...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What have you done so far? Should not be overly complicated

Comment: Something like 
if(days>=30) {
                    locMonth = days/30
remainingDays = Math.ceil(locMonth - Math.floor(locMonth));

Comment: This is elementary school level math ...

Comment: use `/` and `%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this:

```
function(days) {
   var months = parseInt(days / 30);
   days = days - months * 30;
   var weeks = parseInt(days / 7);
   days = days - weeks * 7;
   return (months > 0 ? months + " month" + (months > 1 ? "s, " : ", ") : "") + (weeks > 0 ? weeks + " week" + (weeks > 1 ? "s, " : ", ") : "") + (days > 0 ? days + " day" + (days > 1 ? "s, " : ", ") : "") 
}
```